# Model keyword in Razor View Engine not access ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

https://web.archive.org/web/20210927193940/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081810-1.aspx 
From this link i have build store location app in asp.net mvc 2 it works correctly but when i build this app in asp.net mvc 5 then map is not appearing.
in inspect element there's in an error "Model is not defined". Giving error in this line of code 'Model[0].AdressLatititude' and when I put script like this

init_map('map_canvas', Model[0].AddressLatitude, Model[0].AddressLongitude, 13, @locationsJson, @overlayContentsJson);

So it gives errors on inspect element 'unexpected token' at @locationsJson

```
@model IEnumerable<practmap.Models.NearbyStoreLocation>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "StoreLocatorResults";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/GoogleMapHelpers.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<h2>StoreLocatorResults</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<h2>map</h2>

<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 95%; height: 400px; margin-bottom: 15px; border: solid 1px #333;">
</div>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Store #</th>
        <th>Distance</th>
        <th>Address</th>
    </tr>
    @{

        var locations = new List<string>();
        var infoWindowContents = new List<string>();

        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            locations.Add(string.Format(
                       @"{{
           title: ""Store #{0}"",
           position: new google.maps.LatLng({1}, {2})
     }}",
                       item.StoreNumber,
                       item.Latitude,
                       item.Longitude
                       ));

            infoWindowContents.Add(string.Format(
               @"{{
        content: ""<div class=\""infoWindow\""><b>Store #{0}</b><br />{1}<br />{2}, {3} {4}</div>""
     }}",
               item.StoreNumber,
               item.Address,
               item.City,
               item.Region,
               item.PostalCode)
            );


            <tr>
                <td>
                    @item.StoreNumber
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.DistanceFromAddressDisplay
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Address<br />
                    @item.City,@item.Region<br />
                    @item.CountryCode @item.PostalCode
                </td>
            </tr>





        }

    }

</table>

 @{
var locationsJson = "[" + string.Join(",", locations.ToArray()) + "]";
var overlayContentsJson = "[" + string.Join(",",infoWindowContents.ToArray()) + "]";
 }
<script type="text/javascript">
init_map('map_canvas',Model[0].AddressLatitude,Model[0].AddressLongitude, 13, @locationsJson,  @overlayContentsJson);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@hutchonoid I have successfully done this task. Now map is appearing. I have also put List in model.I have included @html.raw in line of code. Previously,I was having this:

```
@{
var locationsJson = "[" + string.Join(",", locations.ToArray()) +"]";
var overlayContentsJson = "[" + string.Join(",",  infoWindowContents.ToArray()) + "]";
 }
```

After changing.

```
@{
var locationsJson = Html.Raw("[" + string.Join(",", locations.ToArray()) + "]");
var overlayContentsJson = Html.Raw("[" + string.Join(",", infoWindowContents.ToArray()) + "]");
 }
```